# How to change format directly in GoodData

Tags: gooddata

I have exported some data from Paddle in a CSV format. Unfortunately, the CSV format hasn't been recognized because it contains both the date and time.  I didn't manage to change the column in Numbers, neither in Google Drive, as the file is way too big. Is there maybe a way how to change the format directly in GoodData? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The data have to be already transformed when loading to the GD. Generally, the way it's formatted in the CSV doesn't seem to be recognized correctly because it contains both date and time.
[Here](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/data-integration/data-preparation-and-distribution/load-csv-files-to-your-workspace/csv-file-requirements) are the requirements for loading the CSVs. There are some online tools, which allow transforming the data - they can even use google sheets. Alternatively, as a workaround, you could set the time as an attribute - in case this column does not need to be treated as a date, but has to be in the platform."